# Space complexity of node relationship and property

Tags: neo4j, space

Can some one clarify the space complexity of Node Relationship and property in the context of Graph Database . I m currently using Neo4j.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should get familiar with "[Neo4j internals](http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/1396301953/neo4j-internals)" articles from Chris Gioran. For example, in the first one named "[Neo4j Internals: File Storage](http://digitalstain.blogspot.com/2010/10/neo4j-internals-file-storage.html)" you can read the folowing (quote from the article):

> In this post I will try to explain the storage subsystem of Neo4j, exposing the structure and purpose of all those "neostore.*" files that your graph lives in.

Here is his blog: [digitalstain.blogspot.com](http://digitalstain.blogspot.com/)